# whats difference between -key and -signkey parameters of openssl

Tags: openssl

anybody know whats difference between -key and -signkey parameters of openssl:

openssl req -x509 -in server.csr -key server.key -out server.crt -days 365

openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt -days 365

The server.crt content executed by the two commands is different. Which one is correct and can be used as the certification of the web server?